# wamp server 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, wamp, internal-server-error

i have a website running on XAMPP.

i don't know about its version of php that the web site is written by and version of apache too.

I want to move it on windows but got the message `00-Internal server error occurs`.

i did it too ( wamp->apache->apache modules->rewrite-modules ) and restart my wamp but nothing happened.

And here is the error that i see :

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of
>   the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just
>   before this error. More information about this error may be available
>   in the server error log.

What is the solution!

i will be thankful

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail here. The error you've described can mean _many_ different things. First, where are you moving the site's contents from and to?

Comment: Go to error log and copy-paste last error.

Comment: Agree with the above Comments. As a Suggestion, please post your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 17):

You should activate the rewrite module in the file `httpd.conf`.

Change this line :

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to  :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 3):

remove (or move) .htaccess file from your www wamp folder...

Answer (score 2):

Re: 500 Internal Server Error

Check that you have the the apache rewrite module loaded.

go to wamp_manager -> apache -> modules and look for rewrite_module in the list.

If it does not have a TICK beside it click it. Apache will be bounced ( stop, start ). Try again.

The rewite engine will not work without the required module loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Is quite common to use the deflate tag invoking some filters. Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
```

If the **Deflate Module** is enabled, but not **Filter Module**, you will also get the error 500.